# Add nested fields in JSON output in Rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

At the end of a standard Rails controller there is:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.json { render json: @cars }
end
```

Works as expected. Except the JSON doesn't have the associations of `@cars`:

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :model, :color
  belongs_to :manufacturer
end
```

The JSON doesn't have the fields of the manufacturer. How do I get the JSON to have those? Is there something I add to the `belongs_to` call? Is there a way I can add it to the object created from `format.json`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `as_json`, the method, that converts an object to JSON, includes all **attributes**. But `manufacturer` is is a method.

You can instruct `as_json` to include the manufacturer with the option `:methods`, see [api doc](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON/as_json).

So your `Car` model could loo like

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :manufacturer

  def as_json(options={})
    super(options.merge methods: :manufacturer_json)
  end

  def manufacturer_json
    manufacturer.as_json
  end
end
```

to include the manufacturer.

Comment: This answers my question, but applies to all `Car`s. Is there a way to do this only for a particular controller only?

Comment: Not working for me, I don't see any of my extra fields. I'm returning back `{name: 'abcdef'}.as_json` from `manufacturer_json`. But the JSON is exactly as before, no `name` field.

Comment: hmm, started working suddenly, maybe a caching issue.

Comment: you can drop the `as_json` definition in Car and set the option in the controller: `render json: @cars.map{|c| c.as_json(methods:manufacturer_json)}`

Comment: That sounds perfect @MartinM, seems odd that I can pass an array of JSON strings instead of `Car` objects.

Answer (score 1):

My favorite way to do this is with the [Active Model Serializer gem.](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers) With the use of custom serializers, you can achieve almost any JSON structure you'd like, with the exception of using Active Model Serializer for Has Many Through associations, which is currently being overhauled.

You might want to take a look at some tutorials like http://robots.thoughtbot.com/fast-json-apis-in-rails-with-key-based-caches-and